# Statistical analysis for quasi-experiments

Tags: regression, modeling, poisson-regression, frequency, intervention-analysis

This is my first message on this forum. I hope I am not doing any mistake.

I must analyze data obtained after a quasi-experiment and I am not sure how to proceed. The experiment has been carried out in a hospital service where the medical staff has introduced new medical procedures. We would like to assess if after that:
- the frequency at which a diagnostic test is carried out has evolved ;
- the frequency of some binary health outcomes has changed.
--> The data have been collected at the individual level, during one month before the intervention (around 70 patients) and during one month after the intervention (around 70 different patients = not repeated data). There is no control group.

Considering the patient profiles may have changed between the two periods, I was thinking to carry out logistic regressions (adjusted on covariates) for the different parameters of interest. I was however wondering if a Poisson regression might not be an alternative? I also read about interrupted time series. Could it be relevant for this study (knowing the pre/post periods are rather short)?

Comment: So you didn't perform any type of experiment or randomize patients to groups?  If that's the case, you should consider a propensity score analysis using a poisson, quasi-poisson, or negative binomial regression.

Comment: This does not sound like a quasi-experiment. This is just an uncontrolled study that will be horribly confounded via time of year, the Hawthorne effect and all sorts of other problems. Unless you expect a enormous effect of your intervention, there is probably very little point in a statistical analysis.

Comment: I did not take part to the study design. My task was just to propose a statistical analysis plan for this "experiment". On the advice of StatsStudent I did in-depth research on propensity scores and built my statistical analysis plan on this approach. Thank you very much for your feedback.